# how can i write a recursive function of my pseudocode?

Tags: java, discrete-mathematics

Actual code is easier but I'm having trouble finding the base case as well. I was able to write pretty decent pseudocode, but I'm having trouble. I don't know if I'm allowed to ask homework questions on here, but this was a question I could not answer:

> Let f(n) be the number of additions performed by this computation.
>   Write a recurrence equation for f(n). (Note that the number of
>   addition steps should be exactly the same for both the non-recursive
>   and recursive versions. In fact, they both should make exactly the
>   same sequence of addition steps.)

Any help would be great, if I'm not allowed to ask the homework question that's okay.

```
   int sum(int A[], int n ):
     T=A[0];
      for i = 1; to n-1
       T=T+A[i];
        return T;}
```

Comment: We don't *do* other people's homework. However, we don't mind helping a little. We do expect that you show some effort and ask a specific, clear question.

Comment: the second part was the homework, the question i need help with is write my pseudocode recursively

Answer (score 1):

Use the following property of your sum function:

```
   sum(A[], n) == sum(A[], n-1) + A[n]
```

and take into account that:

```
   sum(A[], 1) == A[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just re-wrote your variant

```
   int sum(int A[], int n ):
      if (n > 1){
       T=A[n-1] + A[n-2];
       T += sum(A, n-2) 
      }else{
       if (n > 0) { return A[n -1];}
      }
     return T;
    }
```